# php Gmagick save jpeg quality

Tags: php, jpeg, gmagick

I can't find any property during save or work with Gmagick PHP extension.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php

How can I change JPEG quality in Gmagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setCompressionQuality() was added "2 years, 3 months ago", but does not appear to be documented yet. See [PHP's ViewVC](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=293077)

Comment: Still not documented 6 years after the commit, just [opened a bug on php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71378). Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I *hate* the doc editor, I must be dumb, but I can't figure out what happens after I make an edit: is it committed? Is it in a queue for review? If you have a pointer on some doc on the subject, it might be worth reading as I would jump in more often!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll definitely take some time to read through, I would be nice to be able to edit the doc here and there.